Create maps with Extjs7
I want to know what options there are to integrate maps with Extjs 7. Will there be some open source option, could you help me with some documentation where I can review please. Thank you.
I try loading GeoExt, but I get the following error:
"requires": ["font-awesome", "ux", "GeoExt"],
Loading Build Environment
Cannot satisfy requirements for "GeoExt"!
The following versions cannot be satisfied:
TMS: GeoExt (No matches!)

For using Google maps and calendars you need to use "ext-google" add on.
Refer here:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_addons/getting_started_with_zip.html
